# cassandra upgrade from 0.6 to 0.7.2

Tags: upgrade, cassandra

I followed the instructions in NEWS.txt to upgrade cassandra 0.6 to 0.7.2. 
The instructions are: 
    The process to upgrade is: 
    1) run "nodetool drain" on *each* 0.6 node.  When drain finishes (log 
       message "Node is drained" appears), stop the process. 
    2) Convert your storage-conf.xml to the new cassandra.yaml using 
       "bin/config-converter". 
    3) Rename any of your keyspace or column family names that do not adhere 
       to the '^\w+' regex convention. 
    4) Start up your cluster with the 0.7 version. 
    5) Initialize your Keyspace and ColumnFamily definitions using 
       "bin/schematool   import".  *You only need to do 
       this to one node*.

I did the first three steps. drain node, stop cassandra 0.6, convert old storage-conf.xml to cassandra.yaml. 
I start cassandra 0.7.2 using: "bin/cassandra -f". But it always complains the following errors. I am wondering whether I followed the right instructions. If so, how could i fix this problem?

"Fatal configuration error 
org.apache.cassandra.config.ConfigurationException: saved_caches_directory missing"

Comment: You dont't see an error message like "saved_caches_directory must not be the same as the commitlog_directory" earlier in the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default location for saved_caches_directory is /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches (From [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/StorageConfiguration)). Try to create that manually (dont forget user permissions)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. I should delete old commitLog and files in system directory.